# Node Js Mongoose how to make an update request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to make a put request in which I want to update my database, but I want to protect my old data. For example I have a database like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("601068a96b6bdc1c40a9b67f"),
    "name" : "lamii boudamaa",
    "email" : "dborhene6@gmail.com",
    "msg" : "11",
    "tel" : "2154549",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I have a parameter in my request like this

```
{
    "entreprise" : "aa",
    "poste" : "bb",
}
```

I want to make a fusion with this to get something like this

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("601068a96b6bdc1c40a9b67f"),
        "name" : "lamii boudamaa",
        "email" : "dborhene6@gmail.com",
        "msg" : "11",
        "tel" : "2154549",
        "entreprise" : "aa",
        "poste" : "bb",
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

I wrote this function:

```
router.put('/updateuser',async(req,res)=>{
  var aa=(req.body);
  console.log(aa);
  console.log(req.query);
  console.log(req.query.name);

 User.findOneAndUpdate({'name': req.query.name }, { $set : {req.body} }).then(doc=>{
  console.log('1');
  res.json('success');
  
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))


});
```

but the problem I always get this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6017ede4959d6338a0a2e3c4"),
    "entreprise" : "",
    "poste" : "",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: can you add the schema to the question

Comment: when you log the req.query and req.body, are there correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doesn't look like you are doing anything wrong, if the data being passed in the params and body are correct, you can try passing `{new: true}` as the third parameter in `findOneAndUpdate` query. Something like this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
     {
           'name': req.query.name 
     }, 
     { 
            $set : {
              "entreprise" : req.body.enterprise,
              "poste" : req.body.poste     
            } 
     },
     { new: true}).then(... remaining code
```